# EF Core code-first: cross-schema table relations and GenerateCreateScript()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, npgsql

We are using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v3.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/3.1.4). We are developing unit tests and we would like to have a clean database each time tests are run. We have 2 database schemas and corresponding `DbContext` files:

| **schema** | **DbContext** |
| --- | --- |
| `test1` | `Test1DbContext.cs` |
| `test2` | `Test2DbContext.cs` |

Some tables from schema `test1` reference tables from schema `test2` with foreign keys. When I call `test1DbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().GenerateCreateScript()`, it also outputs script for creating referenced tables from schema `test2`. When `test2DbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().GenerateCreateScript()` is called and its output is executed, it throws the following exception for the tables that were already created by previous call:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P07: relation "<xxx>" already exists'
```

This is the code that we have currently. Pay attention to the comments.

```cs
private void PrepareEmptyDatabase(Test1DbContext test1DbContext, Test2DbContext test2DbContext)
{
    // this drops the *whole* database, not just the `test1` schema
    test1DbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    
    // creates empty database without any schemas
    test1DbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Create();
    
    // create `test1` schema and related tables from schema `test2`
    var script1 = test1DbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().GenerateCreateScript();
    test1DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(script1);
    
    // try to create tables from `test2` schema - exception: some of them already exist,
    // they were created with test1DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(script1)
    var script2 = test2DbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().GenerateCreateScript();
    test2DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(script2);
}
```

Is there a way to re-create the database from C# database models when there are cross-schema foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is no... If you have relationships (foreign keys) between your tables, then these tables should be modeled together in the same EF Core model, using the same DbContext type. A single DbContext can have a model which has tables in multiple schemas - I'd highly advise having a single DbContext here. What is your reason for wanting to do a DbContext-per-schema setup?

As a workaround, you can tell EF Core to not create certain tables in migrations ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#excluding-from-migrations)). So a table can be created via one context, and ignored (for migrations) in the other.